# Notification Handling in react native

Tags: react-native, push-notification, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-firebase

For notification handling in react native , I used react-native-firebase/messaging library for notification handling and firebase cloud messaging as notification provider , it works fine for notification , as it show notification in notification tray.

But notification are not arriving properly like other apps , other apps notifications arrive with a popup which comes over screen and also in notification tray.

Anyone knows the method, please share ...

Any changes which i need to make in AndroidManifest.xml file or additional library which makes it possible to handle notification with popup and also show in notification tray